# How can I extract number from description and set it into another column on pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like the table above.

```
|------------------------------------|
| ID |      Description       | area |
|------------------------------------|
| 1  | House with 80m2        | NaN  |
|------------------------------------|
| 2  | House with 100 meters  | NaN  |
|------------------------------------|
| 3  | House with 90 m2       | 90   |
|------------------------------------|
```

And I have to extract the number information from description column and insert into area when the value is NaN.

```
|------------------------------------|
| ID |      Description       | area |
|------------------------------------|
| 1  | House with 80m2        |  80  |
|------------------------------------|
| 2  | House with 100 meters  |  100 |
|------------------------------------|
| 3  | House with 90 m2       |  90  |
|------------------------------------|
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have only one number (integer) per description, use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) + [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['area'] = np.where(pd.isna(df.area), df.Description.str.extract('(\d+)'), df.area)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   ID            Description area
0   1        House with 80m2   80
1   2  House with 100 meters  100
2   3       House with 90 m2   90
```

Answer (score 0):

To stay in pandas try

`df['area'] = df['area'].fillna(df['des'].str.extract('(\d+)')[0])`